# How to use userdefualts to save a textfield without a button action (swift3)

Tags: ios, swift3, save, uitextfield, nsuserdefaults

I would like to use userdefulats so that when the user goes from view controller a to b and then back to a the text is still there. However I would like to do this without having the user to hit a button to save the textview text. 
[image]

```
import UIKit

 class ViewController: UIViewController {



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {

    optional func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView)


}}
```

Comment: textViewDidChange does not belong inside viewWillDisappear. @J.ren's answer shows how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class ViewControllerA: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

var textView: UITextView?
let textKey = "textKey"

//When view will appear, we should read text we have stored, then display text in textview
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    //We may get nil from UserDefaults
    let storedText = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: textKey) as? String ?? ""
    self.textView?.text = storedText
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    UserDefaults.standard.setValue(self.textView?.text, forKey: textKey)
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //Do textView create here
    //If u create UITextView by IB, u also can finish next work in IB.
    self.textView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100))
    self.textView?.delegate = self
    self.view.addSubview(self.textView!)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//Here we save text in textView everytime we edit textview, but we can delay saving until viewWillDisappear
//    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
//        UserDefaults.standard.setValue(textView.text, forKey: "text")
//        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
//    }
}
```

Comment: what are you saying in //do textView create here.

Answer (score 0):

1. You could just save when they hit the Next button
2. Save on `viewWillDisappear`
3. You can save every time the text changes. Implement `UITextViewDelegate` in your VC and then write this function:

   ```
   optional func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView)
   ```

docs: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextviewdelegate

Comment: I edited my question with you suggestion and it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var txtView: UITextView!
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let myData = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "myData") as? String ?? ""
        self.txtView?.text = myData
    }
    //MARK: - TextView Delegate -
    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        UserDefaults.standard.setValue(self.txtView?.text, forKey: "myData")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }
}
```

If you want to save your text of textView without button click, you have to save it in textViewDidChange delegate method. viewWillDisappear will be called when you navigate to next Controller.